# How to keep log of user actions in a Rails 3 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I want to keep automatically track of user's actions in my rails 3 app. 
I mean, when a user buy a stuff or delete a record, I want to have something like this:

`| User | Action | Model  | IP | DateTime |`
`|User 1   | delete | Product | xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx | 01-10-10 |` 
`|User 2   | create | Product | xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx | 01-10-10 |` 
...

Is there a gem that do this automagically?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [Active Record Versioning](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Active_Record_Versioning) category in ruby-toolbox, there are a lot of gems doing auditing, and more

Answer (score 1):

[acts_as_audited](http://rubygems.org/gems/acts_as_audited) gem can help you here.